# Missing rows from SqlDataReader

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have a very unique problem here...

If I'm going to select data from my database, my datatable will not get all of the database content using a `SqlDataReader`.

```
DataTable DTReader = new DataTable();
string Query = "SELECT CardCode FROM OCRD";

using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    Connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand Command= new SqlCommand(Query, Connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DTReader.Load(reader);
        }
    }

    Connection.Close();
    watch.Stop();

    MessageBox.Show(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
    gridControl1.DataSource = DTReader;
}
```

In OCRD we have some specific userdata where the cardcode is an unique identifier.

CardCode could be D40000, D410000,... and so on.

We definitely have D46000 codes but my datatable will not fetch them. From D40000 to D44999 we can get the data but we are unable to get data above.

The query is definitely correct...

Does anyone has any ideas regarding this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you verify what's actually in the data table? What does `DTReader.Rows.Count` return as opposed to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OCRD`? You could have an issue with how the data is filtered/displayed rather than retrieved.

Comment: Are you sure you're pointed at the same DB?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes I´m pretty sure that it is pointed to the same db.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for your advice. We have a difference here! The datatable.Rows.Count returns a difference of at least 20.000 entries.

Comment: The code you have posted is functionally correct and should read all rows, barring some very unlikely scenarios with pending transactions or snapshot isolation. Double check and then triple check that you are connecting to the correct server and database (do not believe host names, check IPs). Replace the command with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OCRD` and display the result. Is this the same count as you get from executing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OCRD` using Management Studio/sqlcmd? Does adding the schema (`dbo.OCRD`) make a difference?